# Node installation in cpanel doubts

Tags: node.js, cpanel, shared-hosting

I have one domain like **https://example.com** also one subdomain like **https://test.domain.com**. I need to install my node js project into the subdomain, how to install node js project in sub-domain. My doubt is if I installed node in subdomain means it will affect the main domain or not. Kindly clarify my doubts also it needs to change or not in .htaccess

I create SSH key generate based on this reference link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Yx1gZKgb5Y

Comment: Nodejs will be installed on some kind of backend server, now if the core domain and sub domain are pointing to the same ip (meaning same server) then it will be installed for both as its the same system. Although there are ways to install and use node for particular users only.

Comment: @NileshJain Thanks for your quick response. Is it possible to install a node only into a subdomain. Both core and subdomain are pointing to the same IP.

Comment: @NileshJain if I installed node into subdomain means it affect core domain folders or not kindly clarify this one. I'm new to working in Cpanel.

Comment: I would like to know what kind of affect you are talking about. Until unless you have a nodejs project running there it won't affect any of the programs not related to nodejs and if you have nodejs project running then that means nodejs should be already installed and you should worry whether to update the node or not. I don't have knowledge of cpanel but i think what you are asking is about your server (99% linux) and i have answered based on that.

Comment: I don't think you can install nodejs from cpanel on that server.

Comment: @NileshJain I create chat application in node js that one is used in the mobile application. so here I have a domain, in that domain Laravel website is running so if I installed node API in the same server means it will affect the existing website or not. This is the one for my main doubt.

Comment: Installing node on the same server shouldn't affect the php script but just analyse the server load capacity before starting any other application on it.

Comment: Problems can come in terms of load and request handling and also if you update any os level binaries to start your new application may affect the php script. You need to take care of all these things. It would be a good idea to probably do the same thing on some kind of dev server or staging server atleast before touching the production machine.

Comment: @NileshJain Thanks for your suggestion I installed node js in the subdomain, my other domains are working fine